# compile error on format date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to express the following in vba:

```
Format(Sheet2!R[2]C[7], "Short Date")
```

But I keep getting a compile error on the `[2]`, saying: `Expected: List separator or )`

I'm trying to refer to that cell in that format because it is part of a larger formula to be auto-filled. Is there perhaps something that I'm missing?

---

so in the vba, i'll have something like:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A3:A" & rowCount)
```

But cell `A3` isn't filled by vba, it's put in manually in the excel doc as a function like:

```
=Sheet2!B3&" "&Sheet2!A3&" "&Sheet2!C3&"_"&Sheet2!D3&"_"&Sheet2!E3
```

My issue is that the second value in the function `"&Sheet2!A3&"` is actually a date and when it's written comes out like `41331` instead of a typical "dd/mm/yyyy" format. I was hoping to format this value into that human readable format and have it embedded in the function *but* still retain the auto-fill functionality.

Comment: Format(Sheet2.Cells(2,7).Value, "Short Date") I'm not sure about Short Date though, I would use something like Format(Sheet2.Cells(2,7).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")

Comment: thank you for the response. that technique works but the problem is that when i go to auto-fill down on that date. it will increment on that value, *instead* of the following dates in the column of Sheet2

Comment: do you auto-fill in the vba too? Can you show some more code if you do?

Comment: @SamWard sorry for the initial lack of information. i have updated my question with more of it.

Comment: What if you wrap the A3 value in the Text function as so...... =Sheet2!B3&" "&Text(Sheet2!A3,"dd/mm/yyyy")&" "&Sheet2!C3&"_"&Sheet2!D3&"_"&Sheet2!

Comment: @SamWard what you said worked perfectly! put it as an answer, so I can accept it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The VBA can change the cell contents, but then you will lose the formula. Formatting the cell will not help in any event as it contains a string concatenated from many values that cannot be formatted as a date.

Use the Excel [Text(Sheet2!A3,"dd/mm/yyyy")](http://office.microsoft.com/en-za/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx) function shown in the comment by Sam Ward to format the original data in the formula.

Comment: Fed up with posting stuff as answers only to get downvoted be told I should have got more information using comments.. But if I post things in comments people like you come along and blatantly steal my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:D10")` will give you a range. refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836512.aspx

Comment: getting the value isn't the problem. What i need is to auto-fill all values in that 2nd sheet's column. and combine this date into part of a larger string, for each. If i do it the above way, it increments the date, instead of referring to the dates in that 2nd sheet's column.